# Localization and p-adic completion of Integers coincide?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to know if $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ (localization by a prime ideal) and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the completion of p-adic integers) are isomorphic. It seems true, but i don't know how to prove it. Does it holds for every PID?

Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and in both $(p^n)$ are the only ideals

Comment: What we have is that $\mathbb Z_p \cap \mathbb Q = \mathbb Z_{(p)}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is much larger than $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.  Indeed, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is uncountable, since it has an element $\sum a_np^n$ for any sequence of coefficients $a_n\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$.  On the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ (the rationals with denominator not divisible by $p$), so it is countable.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a proper subring of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, and the latter one is complete discrete valuation ring, but $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is *not* complete (but still DVR with respect to the same valuation). However, if you take completion of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ with respect to the $p$-adic norm, you get $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.